# Aurelia View without ViewModel

Tags: aurelia

To configure a route I need a ViewModel and optionally a View, but many times I see that ViewModel is required only to get a html. As result, I stay with many empty classes in js/ts files, just to make router config work.

The question: is there any way to remove this empty classes and configure routes like this:

```
config.map([
    { route: ['', '/'], moduleId: 'no-selection.html',  title: 'Select'},
    { route: 'about', moduleId: 'about.html', title:'About'},
    { route: 'contacts/:id',  moduleId: 'contact-detail',  name:'contacts'}  
]);
```

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to configure a route to a html-only-component yet. Wondered this myself, but half a year ago

Comment: I skipped somes steps and publish [first on GitHub](https://github.com/aurelia/templating-router/issues/49), but I don't receive a feedback yet. And I don't found any answer online. Then, I hope receive  some info here.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't currently possible, but it is an enhancement we would like to do at some point in the future.

Comment: I make a [PullRequest](https://github.com/aurelia/templating-router/pull/50). Can you help me there?

Comment: Pretty sure this is the right answer and you fixed it too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a generic parameterised route with a generic view-model. In the template you can then use "compose" to display the static html...

add a route to your config

```
{'views/:page', moduleId: 'views/index'}
```

in views/index:

```js
export class IndexViewModel {

    private page;

    constructor() { }

    activate(params) {
        this.page = './' + params.page + '.html';
    }

}
```

in views/index.html

```html
<template>
    <compose view="${page}"></compose>
</template>
```